# Errors when providing or generating keys for Simple OAuth module

Tags: 9, authentication-authorization

I'm trying to configure simple_oauth to use with local Lando install of a Drupal 9 site with decoupled React frontend.

I've tried to manually generate the keys in the terminal:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
$ openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout -out public.key
```

...placing the keys into a sibling directory of /web/ and /vendor/ called /keys/.

It throws these error messages:

"The Public Key file does not exist."
"The Private Key file does not exist."

So then I tried pressing the "Generate Keys" button.  When prompted for a "Directory for the keys", I input the same path to that /keys/ folder

Despite copying the output of a pwd from terminal directly into the field, it throws this error:

'Directory "/home/myusername/Desktop/react1/keys" is not a valid directory.'

What am I missing here?

Comment: You didn't define that "it" as is in "It throws these error messages..." but I assume that's a module. Is it? If so, is the directory readable by the web server user?

Comment: Yes, "it" is simple_oauth module.  The tutorial I was following on Drupalize.me showed a standard file path, and I didn't yet realize that using Lando means I had to specify the directory relative to the "/app" project root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working just by using "/app/keys" as the paths on ~/admin/config/people/simple_oauth, instead of the actual path on my machine as in the OP.

I suppose this comes down to me having an opportunity to learn more about Lando+Drupal.